# MvxListView create binding for template layout from code

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Lets say I have a simple Layout with a MvxListView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/LiivControl.Client.Droid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AutoListItems; ItemClick AutoListItemClicked"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/vbmvxautoviewlistitem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My item template layout is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/LiivControl.Client.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_caption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to specify the bindings for the two textview elements in my itemtemplate from code behind. I am not sure how best to go about it. I'm guess I could do something "OnViewModelSet" in the view code behind of the MvxListView. I have tried the following but for it obviously doesn't work because it can't find the control.

```cs
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        IVbMvxAutoListViewModel vm = base.ViewModel as IVbMvxAutoListViewModel;

        TextView title = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_complex_title);
        this.CreateBinding(title).For(x => x.Text).To(vm.ListItemDescriptor.TitlePropName).Apply();

        TextView subTitle = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_complex_caption);
        this.CreateBinding(subTitle).For(x => x.Text).To(vm.ListItemDescriptor.SubTitlePropName).Apply();
        base.OnViewModelSet();
    }
```

My other thought was to somehow intercept the oncreate for the itemtemplate view but OnCreate doesn't get called if I create a view code file for my itemtemplate layout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do the bindings in code it's probably best to:

1. implement a custom `MvxListViewItem`
2. implement a custom `MvxAdapter` to return the custom list view item
3. implement a custom `MvxListView` to use the custom `MvxAdapter`

Not tested, but the code for this is roughly:

#### 1. implement a custom `MvxListViewItem`

```
public class CustomListItemView
    : MvxListItemView
{
    public MvxListItemView(Context context,
                           IMvxLayoutInflater layoutInflater,
                           object dataContext,
                           int templateId)
        : base(context, layoutInflater, dataContext, templateId)
    {
        var control = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_complex_title);
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CustomListViewItem, YourThing>();
        set.Bind(control).To(vm => vm.Title);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create a custom `MvxAdapter`

In this override `CreateBindableView`

```
public class CustomAdapter
    : MvxAdapter
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxListItemView CreateBindableView(object dataContext, int templateId)
    {
        return new CustomListItemView(_context, _bindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId);
    }
}
```

original: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxAdapter.cs#L298

#### 3. implement a custom `MvxListView` to use the adapter

This should be as simple as:

```
public class CustomListView
    : MvxListView
{
    public CustomListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs, new CustomAdapter(context))
    {
    }
}
```

As long as this is in your main UI assembly, this should be useable in your axml as:

```
<CustomListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AutoListItems; ItemClick AutoListItemClicked"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/vbmvxautoviewlistitem" />
```

If `CustomListView` is not in your main UI assembly, then there are some tricks to get MvvmCross to pick it up during your `Setup` - see *Providing Custom Android View Assemblies* in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#wiki-providing-custom-views-android

---

The above is the best way to do this (IMO) - but if you wanted to, then you could do it in less code by just applying the bindings inside the custom adapter and by setting that adapter in `OnCreate` in your `Activity`

Comment: OMG! You r awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe how fast you answered my question. Thanks again!