# Odd issue with MvvmCross, MvxListViewItem on Android

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Have come across an issue using MvvmCross on Android.

I have a MvxListView that has been derived with a custom adapter so that I can show different views for various types of items.  This works fine.

The issue I am seeing is that occasionally I have the following problem.  The MvxListViewItem is created and shown on screen but none of the bindings have taken place (I'm using DelayBind as shown in all of the examples but the Action isn't invoked).  If i then scroll this item offscreen and back again the DelayBind action is executed along with the bindings and the item is populated?

Very odd and has been causing me problems.

Has anyone else come across this and worked it out?

```
class BaseCustomListItemView: MvxListItemView
        {
            public BaseCustomListItemView(Context context, IMvxLayoutInflater layoutInflater, object dataContext, int templateId)
                : base(context, layoutInflater, dataContext, templateId)
            {

                this.DelayBind( () => 
                {
                    this.CreateBinding(this).For( "ProfileImage" ).To<ActivityItemVM>(vm => vm.ActivityUser).Apply();
                } );
            }

            public string ProfileImage
            {
                set 
                { 
                    var nameControl = this.FindViewById<PlayerNameControl>(Resource.Id.name);
                    var imageControl = this.FindViewById<PlayerProfileControl>(Resource.Id.photo);
                    imageControl.SetPlayerId( value, nameControl );

                }
            }

        }
```

My custom adapter looks like the following:

```
class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
        {
            public CustomAdapter(Context context)
                : base(context)
            {
            }

            protected override IMvxListItemView CreateBindableView(object dataContext, int templateId)
            {
                if ( dataContext is EventApprovedActivityItemVM )
                    return new EventApprovedActivityListItemView(base.Context, base.BindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId);

                if ( dataContext is AddedPlayerActivityItemVM )
                    return new AddedPlayerListItemView(base.Context, base.BindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId);

                if ( dataContext is AchievementLevelUpActivityItemVM )
                    return new AchievementLevelUpListItemView(base.Context, base.BindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId);

                if ( dataContext is EventCreatedActivityItemVM )
                {
                    var item = new EventCreatedActivityListItemView( base.Context, base.BindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId );
                    //                  item.ImageId = ( (EventCreatedActivityItemVM)dataContext ).ImageID;
                    return item;
                }

                return new BaseCustomListItemView(base.Context, base.BindingContext.LayoutInflater, dataContext, templateId);
            }

            public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
            {
                var item = GetRawItem(position);
                if (item is EventApprovedActivityItemVM)
                    return 0;
                if (item is AddedPlayerActivityItemVM)
                    return 1;
                if (item is AchievementLevelUpActivityItemVM)
                    return 2;
                if (item is EventCreatedActivityItemVM)
                    return 3;

                return 0;
            }

            public override int ViewTypeCount
            {
                get { return 4; }
            }

            protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
            {
                if (dataContext is EventApprovedActivityItemVM)
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.eventapprovedactivityitem;

                if (dataContext is AddedPlayerActivityItemVM)
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.addedplayeractivityitem;

                if (dataContext is AchievementLevelUpActivityItemVM)
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.achievementlevelupactivityitem;

                if (dataContext is EventCreatedActivityItemVM)
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.eventcreatedactivityitem;

                return base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);
            }

        }
```

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Why are you binding this way?  I would recommend creating your own MvxAdapter and then do the binding through the axml...  In fact binding won't work for you if you don't implement the MvxAdapter.

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my desk to send some more code.  As I mentioned in the original post I do actually create my own MvxAdapter as per the various examples I have seen for MvvmCross. The SetPlayerId does actually do some async work to look up the details of a players image from Facebook.  I've used very similiar code on iOS with no problem.  It's odd as it does work sometimes and occasionally you have items that are not working until you drag them offscreen and back again.  This causes the DelayBind to be invoked and it's fine then.

Comment: `DelayBind` should cause the action to be invoked whenever the DataContext is first set. The DataContext is set by the Adapter - so this could be to do with you custom adapter code? Can you repro this in any sample - e.g. in the polymorphic sample in working with colllections?

Comment: Thanks stuart.  My custom adapter is pretty small so have edited my question and added it in.  Does it look right to you?

Comment: Have looked through. In this case, I don't think you want to use `DelayBind`. `DelayBind` is used to delay the binding action until next time the `DataContext` is set. In Android's `MvxAdapter`/`MvxListItemView` case, the `DataContext` is passed in the ctor - so `DataContext` isn't set again until the cell is reused. (This is different to iOS `MvxTableDataSource`). Can you point me at the samples where you found this - will fix them.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. 

I think I may have got this from some previous stack overflow answers. It's also the way I did it for the ios version as you mention. 

Will try it out tonight when I'm back from the day job and let you know. 

Thanks

Comment: >> Can you point me at the samples where you found this - will fix them. –  Stuart
Hi Stuart, I've trying to solve the same issue; here is the url where you suggested this being the best way to do it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515976/mvxlistview-create-binding-for-template-layout-from-code

any advice for using delayBind