# Android ListView binding programmatically

Tags: mvvmcross

There are many examples of doing this in axml, but I would like to have a complete binding using code behind. To be honest, I would like to have NO axml, but seems like creating all the controls programmatically is a nightmare.

I first tried the suggestions at:
[MvxListView create binding for template layout from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515976/mvxlistview-create-binding-for-template-layout-from-code)

I have my list binding from code-behind, and I get six rows (so source binding is working); but the cells itself does not bind.

Then at the following url:
[Odd issue with MvvmCross, MvxListViewItem on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355573/odd-issue-with-mvvmcross-mvxlistviewitem-on-android#comment52676678_24355573)

Stuart has the following comment: Have looked through. In this case, I don't think you want to use DelayBind. DelayBind is used to delay the binding action until next time the DataContext is set. In Android's MvxAdapter/MvxListItemView case, the DataContext is passed in the ctor - so DataContext isn't set again until the cell is reused. (This is different to iOS MvxTableDataSource).

So in essence, the only example I see shows DelayBind, which shouldn't work.

Can someone please show me some examples... thanks in advance.

---

Added reply to Comments:

Cheesebaron, first of all, a huge thank you and respect for all your contributions;

Now, why not use axml? Well, as programmers, we all have our own preferences and way of doing stuff - I guess I am old school where we didn't have any gui designer (not really true).

Real reasons:

1. Common Style: I  have a setup where Core has all the style details, including what all the colors would be. My idea is, each platform would get the style details from core and update accordingly. It's easy for me to create controls with the correct style this way.
2. Copy-Paste across platform (which then I can even have as linked files if I wanted). For example, I have a login screen with web-like verification, where a red error text appears under a control; overall on that screen I have around 10 items that needs binding. I have already got iOS version working - so starting on Droid, I copied the whole binding section from ios, and it worked perfectly. So, the whole binding, I can make it same across all platform... Any possible error in my way will stop at building, which I think is a major advantage over axml binding. Even the control creation is extremely similar, where I have helpers with same method name.

Ofcourse I understand all the additional layout that has to be handled; to be honest, it's not that bad if one really think it through; I have created a StackPanel for Droid which is based on WP - that internally handles all the layouts for child views; so for LinearLayout, all I do is setup some custom parameters, and let my panel deal with it. Relative is a different story; so far, I have only one screen that's relative, and I can even make it Linear to reduce my additional layout code.

So, from my humble point of view, for my style, code-behind creation allows me to completely copy all my bindings (I do have some custom binding factories to allow that), copy all my control create lines; then only adding those controls to the view is the only part that is different (then again, droid and WP are almost identical). So there is no way I can miss something on one platform and all are forced to be the same. It also allows me to change all the styles for every platform just by changing the core. Finally, any binding error is detected during compile - and I love that.

My original question wasn't about NOT using axml... it was on how to use MvxListView where all the binding is done in code-behind; as I have explained, I got the list binding, but not the item/cell binding working.

Thanks again in advance.

Here is part of my LoginScreen from droid; I think it's acceptable amount of code for being without axml file.

```
            //======================================================================================================
        // create and add all controls
        //======================================================================================================
        var usernameEntry = ControlHelper.GetUITextFieldCustom(this, "Username.", maxLength: 20);
        var usernameError = AddErrorLabel<UserAuthorization, string>(vm => ViewModel.Authorization.Username);
        var passwordEntry = ControlHelper.GetUITextFieldCustom(this, "Password.", maxLength: 40, secureTextEntry: true);
        var passwordError = AddErrorLabel<UserAuthorization, string>(vm => ViewModel.Authorization.Password);
        var loginButton = ControlHelper.GetUIButtonMain(this);
        var rememberMe = new UISwitch(this);
        var joinLink = ControlHelper.GetUIButtonHyperLink(this, textAlignment: UITextAlignment.Center);
        var copyRightText = ControlHelper.GetUILabel(this, textAlignment: UITextAlignment.Center);
        var copyRightSite = ControlHelper.GetUIButtonHyperLink(this, textAlignment: UITextAlignment.Center);

        var layout = new StackPanel(this, Orientation.Vertical)
        {
            Spacing = 15,
            SubViews = new View[]
                {
                    ControlHelper.GetUIImageView(this, Resource.Drawable.logo),
                    usernameEntry,
                    usernameError,
                    passwordEntry,
                    passwordError,
                    loginButton,
                    rememberMe,
                    joinLink,
                    ControlHelper.GetSpacer(this, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, weight: 2),
                    copyRightText,
                    copyRightSite
                }
        };
```

Comment: Why would you not use axml? It works perfectly well in our apps.

Comment: I agree with @Martijn00. It makes no sense not to use it. Otherwise you will end up having to write a lot of code handling all kinds of LayoutParameters etc. which will end up being a huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar situation myself using Mvx4.

The first link you mentioned had it almost correct AND when you combine it from Staurts comment in the second link and just remove the surrounding DelayBind call, everything should work out ok -

```
public class CustomListItemView
    : MvxListItemView
{
    public MvxListItemView(Context context,
                           IMvxLayoutInflater layoutInflater,
                           object dataContext,
                           int templateId)
        : base(context, layoutInflater, dataContext, templateId)
    {
        var control = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_complex_title);
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CustomListViewItem, YourThing>();
        set.Bind(control).To(vm => vm.Title);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

p.s. I have asked for an Edit to the original link to help others.