# How to make synchronized ListViews with items of different height with MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am developing an application that needs to show two columns of images with text and also synchronize their scroll (Pinterest-like).

//////////////////
/                /
/   Image   /
/                /
//////////////////
/    Text     /
//////////////////
/    Text    /
//////////////////

So far I am using the following layout to achieve that.

```
<ScrollViewEx
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:shrinkColumns="0,1"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <MvxLinearLayoutCustomAdapter
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/left_layout"
                android:padding="10dp"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource items1"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/custom_item" />
            <MvxLinearLayoutCustomAdapter
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/right_layout"
                android:padding="10dp"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource items2"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/custom_item" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollViewEx>
```

Notice that I use custom adapter for that LinearLayout for the purpose of using AQuery C# binding to load images into ImageView in my custom item layout and to set various heights for images (to make Waterfall UI).
My adapter code is:

```
public class MvxClickableLinearLayoutAdapter : MvxAdapterWithChangedEvent
{
    IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> src;
    Bitmap imgLoading;
    Context _context;
    public MvxClickableLinearLayoutAdapter(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
    {
        AQuery aq = null;
        var view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent, templateId);
        aq = new AQuery(view);
        if (imgLoading == null)
            imgLoading = aq.GetCachedImage(Resource.Drawable.load);
        if (src == null)
            src = (parent as MvxLinearLayout).ItemsSource.Cast<ItemViewModel>();
        var item = src.ElementAt(position);
        var imageUrl = item.ImageUrl;

        var img = (AQuery)aq.Id(Resource.Id.news_img); 

        img.Image(imageUrl, false, false, 0, 0, imgLoading, 0);
        img.Height(item.Height, true);
        return view;
    }
```

My problem is performance. The adapter loads all elements, that makes me unable to use the ViewHolder pattern. Even if I load a big number of items, adapter does not try to reuse previously loaded views and make my scroll not so smooth. I assume this happens because I use ScrollView. So I thought that my answer is the ListView.

I tried to implement custom ListView as described in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21516206/2214454) but I was unable to put two ListViews in sync (don't want to override 
OnScrollChanged methods because I tried that and there is a delay between two of them). I also need to have control over every item's height so there is no way to make one ListView with two custom items as in picture above.

Is there any way I can achieve that with ListView with the LinearLayouts with custom adapter? Or with ScrollView, maybe by modifying the adapter? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about MvxRecyclerView? That one should be better for preformance and has some hooks for scroll events.

Comment: @Martijn00 I'll try that, thanks. Will it allow me to have same layout as I have in my ScrollViewEx?

Comment: Yeah that should work. Ping me if you need any help implementing it.

Comment: @Martijn00 yes, actually I do need help very much. I am trying to create  a custom adapter based on MvxRecyclerAdapter and to apply it to my MvxRecyclerView. But the Adapter only has a constructor that uses bindingContext as a parameter. How can I get it from my view? Or can you please point me at some tutorial or sample? Thanks for your help.

Comment: var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
            if (recyclerView != null)
            {
                recyclerView.Adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);
}

Comment: @Martijn00, thanks, now adapter gets set. Can you suggest me the way how to make RecyclerView with 2 columns of items with different height? I assume I can control item height and image source in the adapter? And also how can I make it have 2 columns without adding another RecyclerView and overriding OnScrollChanged event?

Comment: recyclerView1.ScrollChange += (object sender, View.ScrollChangeEventArgs e) => {
                    recyclerView2.ScrollY = e.ScrollY;
                };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MvxRecyclerView. That one should be better for preformance and has some hooks for scroll events.

You can use the adapter like this:

```
var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view); 
if (recyclerView != null) { 
    recyclerView.Adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext); 
}
```

Then to add the scrolling to the second list do:

```
recyclerView1.ScrollChange += (object sender, View.ScrollChangeEventArgs e) => { 
    recyclerView2.ScrollY = e.ScrollY; 
};
```